# Unable to match a simple Soap body with 'x-mock-match-request-body' in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-mocks

**Description**

Unable to match a simple Soap body with `x-mock-match-request-body`.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Create an example for a mock server with any url, any http verb and any response

   - e.g. `POST {{url}}/test` with the response:

```
    {
        "test":"test"
    }
```

2. Add the following request body in the example:

```
    <soap:Envelope>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

3. Create a request pointed at the example url with the same body as the example body
4. Send the request
5. Add the header `x-mock-match-request-body` and give the value `true`
6. Send the request

**Expected behavior**

Step 4 is expected to return the example response as the body is not matched and the http verb and url path is correct - this works as expected

Step 6 is expected to return the example response as the body is the same as specified in the example and the http verb and url path is correct - this does NOT work as expected

**Screenshots**

Mock example:
[image]
Mock example headers and response:
[image]

Request with body matching:
[image]
Headers and response:
[image]

Headers and response without body matching:
[image]

- App Type [Native App]
- Postman Version [7.24.0]
- OS: [Windows 10 Enterprise]

I am able to match a JSON-body without issue. Has anyone experienced this when using SOAP?

Comment: In your images the Examples count is 0 - Where are you adding this example? I don't really understand what it is you're trying to achieve - You're mixing XML and JSON in the same request.

Comment: The example is in another request in the same collection. That is no issue. All I want is to match a Soap body. Yes you are certainly correct that the return type is JSON, however that is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the header `Content-type: Application/xml` to both the example and the request and it worked.